# Multiple solutions to the pair of equations $\arg(zw) = \pi$ and $\overline{z} + i \overline{w} = 0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

I was trying to solve the following problem:

> Let $z$ and $w$ be complex numbers such that $\arg(zw) = \pi$ and $\overline{z} + i \overline{w} = 0$. Find $\arg(z)$.

I first used the second equation to get

$$\overline{z} = -i \overline{w}$$

Conjugate both sides to get
$$z = iw$$

So, the first equation gives us:
$$\arg(z) + \arg(-zi) = \pi$$
So,
$$\arg(z) + \arg(-z) + \arg(i) = \pi$$

I thought that $\arg(-z) = \arg(z) + \pi$ (see below figure).

[image]

From which we get, $$\arg(z) = -\frac{\pi}{4}$$

However, the answer given to me is $\frac{3\pi}{4}$. I tried to check the answer and it seems fine too!

Is my working incorrect, or this can have multiple solutions? How can we arrive at $\frac{3\pi}{4}$?

I'd be glad if someone could explain.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that, generally the range of $\arg(z)$ is defined to be $(-\pi,\pi]$. So your claim that $\arg(-z)=\arg(z)+\pi$ won't be true if $\arg(z)\in (0,\pi]$, because in such a case $\arg(-z)$ would be outside the defined range if your formula were used.

Thus, it is better to break
$$\arg(z)+\arg(-zi)=\pi$$
As $$2\arg(z)+\arg(-i)=\pi$$

Which clearly shows that $\arg(z)=\frac {3\pi}{4}$,  since $\arg(-i)=-\frac {\pi}{2}$.